# How to set null value for params when i use gorilla/rpc/json?

Tags: go, json-rpc, gorilla

I tried to send a request to a RPC interface, but the interface doesn't need params. It means the params field should be `"params":[]`, but when I use `json.EncodeClientRequest(method string, args interface{})`, the value of params is always `"params":[{}]` or `"params":[null]`. So it always causes the error: `map[code:-32602 message:Invalid method parameters]`. How could I set a null value for params. Next is my request struct:

```
// request struct
type JsonRpcReq struct {
    Id      uint32       `json:"id"`
    Url     string       `json:"url"`
    Method  string       `json:"method"`
    Params  *interface{} `json:"params"`
    JsonRpc string       `json:"jsonrpc"`
}
```

The error of sentence is:

```
// request method
func (r *JsonRpcReq) Send() (interface{}, error) {
    message, err := json.EncodeClientRequest(r.Method, r.Params)
    fmt.Println(string(message))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ...
}
```

The request sentence is:

```
req := NewJsonRpcReq("http://finance.test.cppp.com/rpc/healthCheck", "status", nil)
```

The `NewJsonRpcReq` method is:

```
func NewJsonRpcReq(url, method string, params *interface{}) *JsonRpcReq {
    return &JsonRpcReq{Id: 0, Url: url, Method: method, Params: params, JsonRpc: "2.0"}
}
```

Comment: Try calling `NewJsonRpcReq` with `[]string{}` instead of `nil` or `interface{}{}`

Comment: I tried it just now, but the content is `{"method":"status","params":[[]],"id":5577006791947779410}`, it still raises the same error.

Comment: Do you control the definition of `JsonRpcReq` or is it some kind of generated code?